# import updated variable data from another script in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, import

test.py

```py
asd = ''

def upd():
    asd = 'Anything'

def hello():
    upd()
    print('hello')
    return asd
```

script.py

```py
import test as tt

print(tt.hello())
```

how can i get updated 'asd' value in script.py ?
anyone please suggest

Comment: Nothing updated `asd`; `test.asd` is a completely different variable from the *local* variable  `asd` defined by the `upd` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't update anything. `upd` created a new local variable that was discarded after the call returned.

If you mean for `upd` to update the *global* variable `asd`, you need to declare the name as global first.

```
asd = ''

def upd():
    global asd
    asd = 'Anything'

def hello():
    upd()
    print('hello')
```

Now, after calling `tt.hello`, you can access `tt.asd` like any other module attribute.

```
import test as tt
tt.hello()
print(tt.asd)
```

(I am intentionally ignoring the issue of whether a function should be mutating the global variable `asd`. There are reasonable use cases for doing so, and not enough context in the question to make any such judgement in this case.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

In test.py

```
asd = ''
def upd():
    return 'Anything'
def hello():
    asd=upd()
    print('hello')
    return asd
```

In script.py

```
import test as tt
asd=tt.hello()
print(asd)
```